# List azure ad using msgraph-sdk-java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to bring current user from azure active directory as follows:

```
            final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("client_id")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .tenantId("tenat_id")
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All"), clientSecretCredential);

        final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
          GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
            .buildClient();

        final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

and I am getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The
> provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided
> value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid
> profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All is
> not valid. Trace ID: b035aaec-9c8a-4728-a237-6d63738adb00 Correlation
> ID: de389e03-9d91-4f4b-aacf-449aa8fac460 Timestamp: 2021-04-05
> 21:44:43Z

any idea that I may be missing?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) here.

> The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the
> resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want,
> affixed with the .default suffix.

The `scope` should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` in your issue.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: After change the scope to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default I am getting the following error:  `com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Error message: Resource '3ff1acff-7a5e-416a-8754-733f38feea81' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
SdkVersion : graph-java/v3.2.0 `

Comment: I fixed the issue replacing `final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();` by `UserCollectionPage userCollectionpage = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();` according to what this post says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3432/microsoft-graph-api-unable-to-get-logged-in-user-d.html